# Is "two-feature classification" appropriate and clear to describe this figure?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

it seems that this figure can be used to elaborates the perceptron model and SVM model:

[image]

Is it appropriate and clear to call this figure "two-feature classification"? Is this a canonical name?

Answer (score 1):

It is a 2 feature classification model. The 2 features are x1 and x2.
Essentially we are using these 2 features to draw a boundary on the data.

Comment: thanks for your answer. would you please give more detail about the boundary? what is the definition? how to draw the boundary?

Comment: So if you see the points in plane we observe 2 colors blue and green. These are the classes or the y variable which we would use to classify the observations. The approach to classify based on the image would be perceptron.

Comment: The working of perceptron can be found here https://towardsdatascience.com/what-the-hell-is-perceptron-626217814f53

Comment: thanks for your reply. the post you linked does talk about the boundary.

Answer (score -1):

The nomenclature I always find on academic books and papers is **binary classification**.

Comment: in "binary classification" the "binary" refers to the fact that the class being predicted can have only two values. The question is about having two features, not a binary class.

Comment: The question was not clear enough, then